# Getting highest resolution data for Costa Rica on Google Earth Engine?

Tags: data, google-maps, google-earth-engine, google

Unless I am just missing it, I am wondering why the DigitalGlobe WorldView data isn't available through Google Earth Engine even though it is on Google Maps?

I want to get as high resolution data for Costa Rica specifically.

Comment: Google composites the best avaliable images from multiple sources so, it is doubtful that you would have sole acces to WorldView. The avalible image composites will be RGB sans the NIR band reqired for NDVI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the licensing agreement between Google and Digital Globe. Providing composites as a layer in Google Maps is completely different to providing users the full dataset for (commercial) use.

All public datasets in GEE [require a free license.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-earth-engine-developers/iABjFqBkLAk/EdeXVOdtEAAJ) You can however ingest datasets you bought from Digital Globe and process them on GEE.

Answer (score -1):

I also need to do image processing High-Resolution Imagery, I was looking for in catalog, found this [enter link description here](https://explorer.earthengine.google.com/#detail/USDA%2FNAIP%2FDOQQ)

Comment: Yes, you can process those images in GEE. But the question itself its related to Costa Rica, not for only USA

Comment: it doesn't answer it since this is only for the US